# Infragistics UltraWebToolbar.v5.2 generates "Input string was not in a correct format" in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

When running an application in `Chrome` and `Firefox`, `Infragistics UltraWebToolbar.v5.2` control generates "Input string was not in a correct format" exception.

`IE` is working fine.

Are there any reasons for and solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in a later volume and you could upgrade to 2011 Volume 1 to resolve this.  Note that is the last volume that has the UltraWebToolbar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot try that since my company does  not want to upgrade to the latest set of controls